# Transcribing data from one table format to another in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have (in the same sheet) two tables of data. The first starting at A1 looks like:

```
  A      B        C
1 Struct Material Quantity
2 ABC    XYZ      2
3 ABC    LMN      4
4 DEF    XYZ      1
5 DEF    KOL      5
...
```

The second table of data starting at G1 looks like:

```
  G        H   I
1 Material ABC DEF ...
2 XYZ
3 LMN
4 KOL
...
```

Table 1 is guaranteed to be sorted ascending using column A, then column B.

Each unique/distinct Struct from table 1 appears exactly once in table 2 somewhere from H1 or to the right of H1 (basically becomes the header for table 2). Each unique/distinct Material from table 1 appears exactly once from A2 down (becomes the row "header"). For example, even though Material XYZ appears twice in table 1, it appears once in the row headers in table 2.

I want to fill the Quantity from table 1 into the corresponding table 2 cell.

Is there a formula in Google Sheets which I can put into table 2 cells that will automatically search for the correct Quantity in table 1?

So the value in H2 do something like:

1. Search for H1 ("ABC") in column A. This may return a range (so in our example A2:A3).
2. Search for G2 ("XYZ") in range in column B but restricted to the row range from step 1 above (so in our example B2:B3).
3. Copy the value from column C and from the row from step 2 above, or nothing ("") if not found.

I have tried a number of built in formulas but cannot seem to do nested searches/VLOOKUPs/MATCHs/INDEXs/etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(G2:G,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,bycol(H1:1,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,sumifs(C:C,B:B,Σ,A:A,Λ)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Very complex answer, thank you. Unfortunately I cannot understand how it works. And my sheet has changed a little and probably is why it is not working for me. Basically table 2 now starts at I1 rather than G1. (2 columns over to the right!) Could you explain how your solution works?

Comment: map part (`map(G2:G,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,`) is traversing and processing the *Material* present in `G2:G` and at the same time bycol part (`bycol(H1:1,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,`) is traversing horizontally across `H1:1` picking the *struct*. To put it simply in cell_H2 (above screenshot) the formula in backend would be `sumifs(C:C,B:B,XYZ,A:A,ABC)`; in cell_I2 it would be `sumifs(C:C,B:B,XYZ,A:A,DEF)` ; in cell_H3 it would be `sumifs(C:C,B:B,LMN,A:A,ABC)`& so on...