# How to extend a formula to a 2D array in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I wish to create and extend the following table in Google Sheets to more rows and columns but cannot use table headers (both row and column) inside the formula. I either have to code value hard as mentioned below or I have tp update the data range when I extend the formula. Both of these require significant manual input.

|  | Me | Dad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Category1 | =SUMIFS(Apr!G:G, Apr!E:E, "Me",Apr!F:F , "Category1") | =SUMIFS(Apr!G:G, Apr!E:E, "Dad",Apr!F:F ,"Category1") |
| Category2 | =SUMIFS(Apr!G:G, Apr!E:E, "Me",Apr!F:F ,""Category2") | =SUMIFS(Apr!G:G, Apr!E:E, "Dad",Apr!F:F ,"Category2") |

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [this could be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77703373/5479575)

Comment: Why `cannot use table headers`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(Apr!E:E&Apr!F:F,B1:C1&A2:A3,Apr!G:G))
```

Comment: i don't want to extend this to all columns.. i only want the formula to be applied to a few cells

Comment: can you share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result? You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)